# implementation of angular.isBoolean?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

I was reviewing some source code and underscore/lodash was included just for the `_.isBoolean` function.  The [underscore source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) is below:

```
_.isBoolean = function(obj) {
    return obj === true || obj === false || toString.call(obj) == '[object Boolean]';
};
```

Looking at [Function components in ng](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function) I see similar functions (`angular.isObject`, `angular.isString`, `angular.isNumber`, etc), but no `angular.isBoolean` function.

The [angular.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js) source has this an internal function (source below), but an issue requesting to make public ([feat: register isBoolean as a public member of global angular #5185](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5185)) was closed saying "other libraries like underscore and lodash solve these problems well".

```
function isBoolean(value) {
  return typeof value === 'boolean';
}
```

**Questions**:

- My initial reaction was to copy `isBoolean` and make a named function in my code, but which implementation is more correct?
- Do I use the underscore version in anticipation of compatibility with a future upgrade?
- I assume it is a bad idea to "duck punch" my implementation into `angular.isBoolean`?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to a local function"?

Comment: Do you understand the differences between the functions? Then you should know that there is no "more correct" one.

Comment: @Bergi - edited question and reworded "convert to a local function"; asking "more correct" more for future readers than myself

Comment: I wouldn't use Angular's in your own code.  They are making an assumption that you'll never be passing a boxed boolean which may hold up for their code but not yours. `isBoolean(new Boolean(true)) != _.isBoolean(new Boolean(true))`

Comment: @BrianNickel At the same time, I can't imagine when people need to actually use a boxed boolean

Comment: @Ian Somebody must've. The check was added two years after the project started: https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/commit/4fa97eb2fa7c387913bead871767912ab22d5ee2 :) I actually think I remember seeing Modernizr using them.

Comment: @BrianNickel Oh you're obviously right, I'm sure the underscore devs wanted to make sure they covered all cases (which isn't a bad idea for such a popular library). But I guess my point was I can't imagine why someone would **need** to use boxed primitives. Interesting about Modernizr though, I'm gonna go look in their source for it (and maybe some reasoning?)

Comment: @Ian https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/search?q=new+Boolean&type=Code For properties. If true, the value has properties with specific details. Really any object would work (be truthy) but maybe they're dealing with consumers doing `result == true`.

Comment: @BrianNickel And you are right, Modernizr uses it for detecting the ability to play videos (among a few other things). An example is: `bool = new Boolean(bool); bool.ogg = SOMETHING; bool.webm = SOMETHING_ELSE; return bool;`. While it accomplishes what they set out to do, I personally just don't like that approach (compared to returning an object literal with properties). It's just weird that most of the library will return a boolean primitive, making things like this inconsistent (and "breaking" the consistent use of `===`)

Comment: @Ian: When [searching GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=javascript&q=new+Boolean&type=Code), I've only found it in a) test cases b) spec quotes :-)

Comment: @Bergi Did you check all 100 pages? Haha good idea though, and good to hear. At least I'm not crazy (or at least people don't use it as much as I expected)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I was reviewing some source code and underscore/lodash was included just for the _.isBoolean function. […] My initial reaction was to convert isBoolean to a local function

Yes, good idea (if you emphasize the *just*). Maybe not even a function, but simply inline it.

> but which implementation is more correct?

They behave differently when objects that are instances of the [`Boolean` class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) are passed in. Will such ever occur in the app you are reviewing? Probably not. If they do, only you will know whether you want to consider them as booleans.

Apart from that, `val === true || val === false` has the same effect as `typeof val == "boolean"`.

> I assume it is a bad idea to "duck punch" my implementation into `angular.isBoolean`?

It's unlikely that angular will ever do this, so you hardly will provoke a collision. Still, ask yourself: Is it actually useful there? Will other code use it? For more discussion, have a look at [*Don't modify objects you don't own*](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/).